# Unable to validate the configuration by running botium in emulator mode

Tags: automation, automated-tests, chatbot

I'm trying test automation for Watson chatbot as described [here](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/10-minutes-codeless-test-automation-for-ibm-watson-chatbots-d71eac9626d7).

I installed `botium-cli`. But unable to validate the configuration by running Botium in emulator mode

```
botium-cli emulator --config path/to/botium.json
Error: Loading Botium plugin failed
at Validate.Validate.then (C:....\botium-cli\node_modules\botium-core\src\containers\PluginConnectorContainer.js:56:15)
```

Is there a problem in installing the botium package, or it something to do with the `botium.json`?

Answer (score 0):

The command line with the phrase path/to/botium.json is the problem. You have to point it to the actual directory containing your botium.json file. There is more feedback if adding the -verbose flag to the call.

Comment: Yes I pointed to the actual directory containing the botium.json..   I tried with -v and see this error

Comment: botium-PluginConnectorContainer Loading Botium plugin from watsonconversation failed - { Error: Cannot find module 'watsonconversation'                                                      botium-PluginConnectorContainer Loading Botium plugin botium-connector-watsonconversation failed, try "npm install botium-connector-watsonconversation" - { Error: Cannot find module 'botium-connector-watsonconversation'

Comment: when I tried to do  npm install botium-connector-watsonconversation, I got below 
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: botium-connector-watsonconversation@latest

Comment: The mentioned article was outdated, i just updated it: instead of "watsonconversation" it should be "watson" in botium.json.

Comment: Changing every occurence of "watsonconversation" to "watson" in the botium.json  fixed the error. But now I get error related to credentials..I have provided the same credentials that I use for my watson account

Comment: This is the error : Error: Cannot build watson container: 'Watson workspace connection failed: { Error: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.   and this is how my botium.json looks now  {
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "test",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "watson",
      "WATSON_USER": "<my actual watson ibm id>",
      "WATSON_PASSWORD": "<my actual watson password>",
      "WATSON_WORKSPACE_ID": "<my actual watson workspace id>",
      "WATSON_USE_INTENT": true
    }
  }
}

Comment: The user and password to use here are NOT the same you are using for logging into the Watson workspace. In most cases, you will have to [generate service credentials](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-credentials.html#creating-credentials). I updated the blog article to reflect this. thanks for the pointer.

Comment: updated as per above and got timedout error now.                                    
    botium-PluginConnectorContainer Botium plugin botium-connector-watson loaded +297ms
  botium-connector-watson Validate called +0ms
  botium-connector-watson Build called +7ms
  botium-connector-watson Watson checking workspace status before proceed +6ms
  botium-BotDriver BotDriver Build error: Error: Cannot build watson container: 'Watson workspace connection failed: { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect

Comment: sometimes Watson is not responsive. ETIMEDOUT is a completely different kind of problem. you my try to enable debug mode ("export DEBUG=botium*"), but there is nothing to do but wait.

Comment: I'm wondering if the time out has something to do with proxy set up..  Is there a way to mention the proxy details in botium .json ?

Comment: The botium JSON file doesn't have a field for the watson api URL. Could that be an issue here ?

Comment: You can use the WATSON_URL capability to change it (see https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/wiki/operation-mode-watson), depending on your IBM Cloud subscription it may be required to change it.


As the watson sdk uses the "request" library under the hood, it should be possible control proxy settings with environment variables, see https://github.com/request/request#controlling-proxy-behaviour-using-environment-variables